# Conditional Formatting refering to the current row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

My problem is really simple:

> For each row : if column A is not empty then column C should have a color.

So in the conditional formatting rules manager (after have previously selected all column C) I tried formulas with concatenate, indirect, ROW, thiscellerow, with I don't know what again, without anything, with an equal condition (just to test it), I'm giving up ...

For the moment my formula is:

```
=INDIRECT("$A"&ROW())<>""
```

Excel automatically changes into this:

```
="INDIRECT(""A""&ROW())<>""""" (to escape all the ")
```

Anyone could help me on this please ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are making it way too difficult.

```
Rule: =$A1<>""
Applies to: =$C$1:$C$10 (you define your own end)
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your reply
I've already test easier things like that and it is not working neither.
I just tried your rule and indeed it is not working :(

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I updated my answer with a working view of the code.

Comment: Man ... I don't know what I did wrong but seeing your screenshot I told to myself "f**cking impossible !!!" I tried another time, it works perfectly fine !
So thank you very much xD

Comment: Haha :P You're welcome. Do note that Excel quite often f*cks up your conditional formatting formula the first time. Changing it a second time normally does the trick for me :)